# Jquery Ajax call not working in Rhodes

Tags: jquery, ajax, rhomobile, rhodes

In my application i am using simple Jquery Ajax call, but it is not working. Here is my code

```
      try{
          $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "http://xxxxxxx/sites/weed/chkuseremail_response.php?user_name=hhhhh&type=user&email=test@test.com",
               async: false,
               success: function(result) {
                        alert("result "+result);
                        alert("result.response "+result.response);
                        alert("result.error "+result.error);

                                  var error = result.error;
                                  var response = result.response;
                                  if (error == null || error == "null") {
                                      alert("welcome1");
                                  }
                                  if (response == null || response == "null") {
                                       alert("welcome2");
                                  }

                                  },
                                       error: function() {
                                              alert("welcome3");
                                              }
                                       });

           }catch(e)  {alert(e);

}
```

I am using rhodes 3.0.2.

Comment: here the output is result = "", result.response = null, result.error = null, also i got all the three alerts welcome1,welcome2,welcome3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of cross-domain policy restrictions.

When you're browsing a site, for security reasons, ajax calls to other hosts are disabled by the browser.

The same thing is happening for your Rhodes application, you can't call a web service that's not running on the same domain of your application.

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to be able to get external JSON data.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have fixed this issue with callback and jsonp